# Clustered ColumnStore Index in Standard edition of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is Clustered ColumnStore Index there in STANDARD Edition of SQL Server 2016? I am not able to get microsoft msdn documentation for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link and a comment I found, seem to indicate it's available only for Enterprise Editions.  [Features for 2016 Editions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)

Comment: As of 2016 SP1 clustered columnstore is available in standard edition with lower memory limits (32GB)

Answer (score 1):

It is available in 2016 SP1 Standard, read here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/columnstore-index-standard-and-express-editions-with-sql-server-2016-sp1/